# Please explain the tenses in the second line

Tags: tenses, poetry

It's a pretty famous poem from Kipling's "Just So Stories." It begins thus:

I KEEP six honest serving-men
 **(They taught me all I knew)**;
Their names are What and Why and When
 And How and Where and Who.
I send them over land and sea,
 I send them east and west;
But after they have worked for me,
 I give them all a rest.

Comment: *Know* doesn't rhyme with *who*.

Comment: Who's being frivolous now? Or are you serious?

Comment: You mean taught or knew doesn't sound right or shoud be changed?

Comment: @Rathony - You tell me. I'm stumped.

Comment: I'm serious.  It's called poetic license.  The Kipster uses the enduring present (*keep*, *send*) and the present perfect (*have worked*), meaning that he's employing his inquisitive methods up to and including the present and intends to keep using them.  This clashes with the past tense *knew*, which taken literally means that they've taught him what he knew in the past.  Odd to omit what he knows now.  We expect, "taught me all I know" keeping the teaching and the learning apace.  But that's not gonna work for the rhyme scheme.

Comment: @deadrat This is unmistakably the right answer. Of course it's poetic license. Why don't you post it? An accepted answer is more useful for the community than just a bunch of comments, no?

Comment: @A.P. OK, done, but I'm not sure Ricky is gonna go for it.

Comment: @deadrat At least the good folks here will upvote it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called poetic license. Kipling uses the enduring present (*keep*, *send*) and the present perfect (*have worked*), meaning that he's employing his inquisitive methods up to and including the present and intends to keep using them. This clashes with the past tense *knew*, which taken literally means that they've taught him what he knew in the past. Odd to omit what he knows now. We expect, "taught me all I know" keeping the teaching and the learning apace. But that's not going to work for the rhyme scheme.

If anyone can rephrase to make both tenses and rhyme work without hurting the poem, then you're a better man than I am, Gunga Din.

Comment: Poetic license, then. I'm not a great fan of the concept. But, being a debonair, amicable, and oftentimes objective person who genuinely likes you against all odds, I must accept your answer as correct. Bummer. As for being Gunga Din, well: "They once taught me all I knew." The extra syllable gives it a good anapestic turn at the beginning of the line.